# Trying to add elements to a list inside "for" loop overwrites the same value each time

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given the following:

```
data = response.json()
for result in data['results']:
    for field in result['custom_fields']:
        if field['id'] == some_id_field:
            print(field['value'])
```

Returns:

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
55555
66666
77777
```

However, I wanted to store the output as list in a separate variable to use later so I did this:

```
data = response.json()
for result in data['results']:
    for field in result['custom_fields']:
        if field['id'] == some_id_field:
            var_for_later = field['value']
            var_for_later = var_for_later.splitlines()
            var_for_later = var_for_later
```

But instead, it only returns the first element in the array:

```
11111
```

Instead of `['11111','22222','33333','44444','55555','66666','77777']`

Why is `field['value']` now only storing the first element when assigned to a variable?

Comment: `var_for_later = field['value']
            var_for_later = var_for_later.splitlines()
            var_for_later = var_for_later` what is happening here? You are storing new value to `var_for_later`. Are you looking for `var_for_later=[] var_for_later.append()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the value to a variable, not appending it to list. In order to store the values in list, you need to update your code to create an empty list before the `for` loop and append the `field['value']` to list by using `list.append()` method. Hence, your code will become:

```
data = response.json()

my_list = []  # creating empty list
for result in data['results']:
    for field in result['custom_fields']:
        if field['id'] == some_id_field:
            my_list.append(field['value'])  # Appending items to the list
```

which will return you the `my_list` as list in your desired format as:

```
[11111, 22222, 33333, 44444, 55555, 66666, 77777]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
yourdata = []
data = response.json()
for result in data['results']:
    for field in result['custom_fields']:
        if field['id'] == some_id_field:
            yourdata.append(field['value'])

print(yourdata)
```

I guess you're pretty new to Python, so I suggest you to watch some tutorials or search for documentation on the internet. E.g. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp)

### Why didn't your code work?

Have a look at this line: `var_for_later = var_for_later` It does absolutely nothing. Also, you overwrite var_for_later in every iteration. So it should technically return '77777' and not '11111' in the end.

Are you sure this is the output that corresponds to this code?

Btw, do you really have multiple entrys with the same id?

Answer (score 1):

Earlier you were printing one field at a time, but then you started replacing the same variable in every loop which is why it jas only one value. `var_for_later` only exists within that for loop. In stead create your final list outside the loop and append values in every iteration.

```
out = []
data = response.json()
for result in data['results']:
    for field in result['custom_fields']:
        if field['id'] == some_id_field:
            out.append(field['value'])
```